# Url Routing asp.net 4 webforms - not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, url-rewriting, url-routing

I am setting up a test route for the first time on my development machine.

The problem I am having is that I am getting a 404 error when attempting the test.
e.g. http://domain.local/about

I am using this article by [Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)

Win 7 64bit
Visual Studio 2010 / asp.net webforms 4.
iis7.5 with website using integrated managed pipes in the application pool.

I have the following routes in my global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

private void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.Clear();
    routes.MapPageRoute("about route", "about", "~/about.aspx");
}
```

The code does get hit.

I have also tried re-registering asp using aspnet_regiis.exe -i

any suggestions?

Comment: I can get this to work using the Classic mode settings, ala, add Handler Mappings of * to asp dll. Currently I cannot get this to work with integrated mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any issue with your code. Make sure you restart the ASP.NET development server.

Comment: The problem seems to be with integrated managed pipes application pools.  If I select asp.net 4 classic and add a Handler Mapping of wildcard to the asp dll, it works.